# Как произвести переинициализацию приложения angular на том же контейнере?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть приложения на angular, появилась необходимость произвести переинициализацию.
angular 1.5.0
Не уверен в правильности своих мыслей, посему буду благодарен за любую помощь в этом направлении.

```
window.app = angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])
```

инициализация

```
app.get('$rootScope').$destroy()
```

destroy - правда не совсем уверен, что это действительно удаляет приложение, но ничего лучше не нашёл

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])
```

после повторной инициализации, получаю в консоль:

angular.js:1672 Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element 'document'(…)

видимо не удалил я приложение, хотя весь функционал работать перестал

Есть ли способ сделать повторную инициализацию на том же контейнере?

Comment: почему вы думаете что _нужно произвести переинициализацию_? Какую проблему вы хотите так решить?

Comment: Необходимо положить новую схему(svg) в контейнер, провести инициализацию активных эелементов схемы, новые элементы должны попасть в контекст angular, первая мысль, что нужно прибить приложение и заново запустить, либо руками во все модули angular подкладывать новые элементы и всё что с ними связано

Comment: это так не работает. Приводите код который есть с описанием что должно получиться Скорее всего нужен вызов `scope.apply` для обновления данных

Comment: Нет нужды в коде, я хотел лишь узнать можно ли убить приложение и заново развернуть на том же контейнере

Comment: на том же контейнере нет, но можно сделать его точную копию - удалить контейнер добавить копию и развернуть на копии